# Android Spinner: Populate second and thrid spinner based on first spinner filter

Tags: sqlite, android-sqlite

**Same question header is available but requirement is different.**

First spinner selection should load from database and second spinner and third spinner should change based one first spinner selection.

**Current:**

[image: Spinner1 Display all records] - [image: Spinner2&Spinner3 display based on spinner1]

As i can see there is something wrong in sql query which i am unable to find.

**Issue :**

1. Spinner1 should display ignore the duplication instead of two P1 it should display like P1,P2,N1.
2. Spinner2 should display all records which relevant to P1 whereas its shows only one record

**Requirement :**

Second spinner and third spinner should populate data based on first spinner whereas challenge is second spinner should display all data which is matched by spinner1.

**Layout:SpinnerEx4Activity**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="fill_parent" android:orientation="vertical">

  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="8dip" android:text="@string/lblAcc" />

  <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner4" android:layout_width="138dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" />

  <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner1" android:layout_width="368dp" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:drawSelectorOnTop="true" android:layout_toRightOf="@+id/spinner4" android:layout_alignBaseline="@+id/spinner4" />

  <TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:padding="8dip" android:text="@string/lblSubAcc" />

  <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner2" android:layout_width="fill_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:layout_marginTop="10dip" android:layout_marginLeft="8dip" android:layout_marginRight="8dip" />

  <TextView android:id="@+id/textView2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Visit Day" />

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox2" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Sunday" />

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Monday" />

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox4" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Tuesday" />

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox5" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Wednesday" />

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox6" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Thursday" />

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Saturday" />

  <CheckBox android:id="@+id/checkBox7" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Outlet is Closed" />
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView6" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="false" android:text="Total Outlet" android:textSize="10dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView7" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="false" android:text="T Outlet" android:textSize="19dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_weight="1" />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView9" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="false" android:text="Completed Outlet" android:textSize="10dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_weight="1"
    />
    <TextView android:id="@+id/textView8" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="false" android:text="C.Outlet" android:textSize="19dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_weight="1" />
  </LinearLayout>

  <Spinner android:id="@+id/spinner3" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" />

  <EditText android:id="@+id/input_label" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="0dp" android:ems="10" android:inputType="textPersonName" />

  <Button android:id="@+id/btn_add" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:text="Save" />
  <LinearLayout android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:orientation="horizontal">

    <Button android:id="@+id/btnexport" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="false" android:text="Download" android:textSize="15dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_weight="1" />

    <Button android:id="@+id/btn_send_mail" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="false" android:text="Send" android:textSize="15dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_weight="1" />

  </LinearLayout>

  <Button android:id="@+id/btn" android:layout_width="match_parent" android:layout_height="wrap_content" android:scrollHorizontally="false" android:text="Import" android:textSize="15dp" android:textStyle="bold" android:layout_weight="1" />

</LinearLayout>
```

**MainActivity.Java**

```
public class SpinnerEx4Activity extends AppCompatActivity {

    Spinner s1,s2,s3,s4;
    Button btnAdd;
    Button send;
    Button ok;
    Button btn_send_mail;
    private Button btnexport;
    EditText inputLabel;
    TextView tex,tex1;
    DatabaseHandler dbhndlr;

    Cursor spinner1csr, spinner2csr, spinner3csr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter sca, sca2,sca3;
    long spinner1_selected = 0;
    long spinner4_selected = 0;
    long spinner3_selected = 0;
    CheckBox ck1,ck2,ck3,ck4,ck5,ck6,ck7,ck8;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_spinner_ex4);

        s1 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        s2 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        s3 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        s4 = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner4);
        btnAdd = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_add);
        inputLabel = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.input_label);
        dbhndlr = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        ck1=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox);
        ck2=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox2);
        ck3=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox3);
        ck4=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox4);
        ck6=(CheckBox) findViewById(R.id.checkBox5);
        ck7=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox6);
        ck8=(CheckBox)findViewById(R.id.checkBox7);
        final Button btnexport = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btnexport);
        btn_send_mail = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_send_mail);
        ok = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn);
        loadSpinnerData();
        TextView tex = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView7);
        TextView tex1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.textView8);
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(dbhndlr.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LABELS) < 1) {
            dbhndlr.insertlabel("1" ,"P1","Henry","9001234");
            dbhndlr.insertlabel("2","P1","Malik","9004567");
            dbhndlr.insertlabel("3","P2","ermarket","900356");
            dbhndlr.insertlabel("4","N1","Veli","9003456");
        }
        if (DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(dbhndlr.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LABELS1) < 2) {
            dbhndlr.insertlabel12("14","0001 Daily");
            dbhndlr.insertlabel12("21","0007 Weekly");
            dbhndlr.insertlabel12("34","0014 Days");
            dbhndlr.insertlabel12("44","0021 Days");
            dbhndlr.insertlabel12("54","0028 Days");

        }
        spinner1csr = dbhndlr.getAllLabelsAsCursor();

        s1.setAdapter(sca);

        sca3 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,spinner1csr,
                new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_ID1},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );


        s4.setAdapter(sca3);

            class SendMail extends AsyncTask <String, Integer, Void> {

                private ProgressDialog progressDialog;

                @Override
                protected void onPreExecute() {
                    super.onPreExecute();
                    progressDialog = ProgressDialog.show(SpinnerEx4Activity.this, "Please wait", "Sending mail", true, false);
                }

                @Override
                protected void onPostExecute(Void aVoid) {
                    super.onPostExecute(aVoid);
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }

                protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
                    Mail m = new Mail("d.com", "t3e");


                    String[] toArr = {"fdm.bh"};
                    m.setTo(toArr);
                    m.setFrom("owMobile");
                    m.setSubject("This is emaster Data Application");
                    m.setBody("Find attached excoute,Thank you.");
                    try {


                        m.addAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory()+"/android/data/com.example.ok.myapplication/files/w.csv");

                        if(m.send()) {
                            Toast.makeText(SpinnerEx4Activity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        } else {
                            Toast.makeText(SpinnerEx4Activity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                        }
                    } catch(Exception e) {
                        Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
                    }
                    return null;
                }

            }
        });



///////////////////////////////

        s4.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
            @Override
            public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id1) {

                spinner4_selected = id1;
                spinner1csr = dbhndlr.getByRowid(spinner4_selected);
                spinner2csr = dbhndlr.getByRowid(spinner4_selected);
                sca.swapCursor(spinner1csr);
                sca2.swapCursor(spinner2csr);
            }

            @Override
            public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
            }
        });

        sca = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                spinner1csr,
                new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );


        sca2 = new SimpleCursorAdapter(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                spinner1csr,
                new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_ID},
                new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                0
        );

        s1.setAdapter(sca);
        s2.setAdapter(sca2);


    private void loadSpinnerData() {

        DatabaseHandler db = new DatabaseHandler(getApplicationContext());

        List<String> lables = db.getAllLabels();


        ArrayAdapter<String> dataAdapter1 = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, lables);


        dataAdapter1
                .setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);

        /
        s3.setAdapter(dataAdapter1);
    }
    @Override
    public void onDestroy() {
        spinner1csr.close();
        spinner2csr.close();
        spinner3csr.close();
        super.onDestroy();

    }



    protected Void doInBackground(String... params) {
        Mail m = new Mail("d.com", "4@");


        String[] toArr = {"d.gw"};
        m.setTo(toArr);
        m.setFrom("Mata");
        m.setSubject("This is tion");
        m.setBody("Find ute,Thank you.");

        try {


            m.addAttachment(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/Android/data/com.example.ok.myapplication/files/ce.csv");

            if (m.send()) {
                Toast.makeText(SpinnerEx4Activity.this, "Email was sent successfully.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(SpinnerEx4Activity.this, "Email was not sent.", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Log.e("MailApp", "Could not send email", e);
        }
        return null;
    }
}
```

**Database**

```
    public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        // Database Version
        public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

        public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinnerExample";
        private static String DB_PATH = "/data/data/com.example.ok.myapplication/databases/";
        private final Context myContext;
        private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
        // Database Name
        // Labels table name
        public static final String TABLE_LABELS = "labels"; //<<<< Made public
        public static final String TABLE_LABELS1= "labels1";
        public static final String TABLE_LABELS2= "labels2";
        // Labels Table Columns names
        public static final String KEY_ID4 = "input_label";
        public static final String KEY_ID12 = "id2";           //<<<< Made public
        public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
        public static final String KEY_99 = "sno";           //<<<< Made public//<<<< Made public
        public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";       //<<<< made public
        public static final String KEY_ID1 = "id1";           //<<<< Made public
        public static final String KEY_NAME1 = "name1";
        public static final String KEY_1 = "number";           //<<<< Made public
        public static final String KEY_2 = "outletname";       //<<<< made public
        public static final String KEY_3 = "sunday";           //<<<< Made public
        public static final String KEY_4 = "monday";
        public static final String KEY_5 = "tuesday";
        public static final String KEY_6 = "wednesday";
        public static final String KEY_7 = "thursday";
        public static final String KEY_8 = "saturday";
        public static final String KEY_9 = "closed";
        public static final String KEY_10 = "calling";
        public static final String KEY_11 = "id3";
        public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
            myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
            this.myContext = context;
            Log.e("Path 1", DB_PATH);
        }

        // Creating Tables


        public void openDataBase() throws SQLException {
            String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            myDataBase = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READWRITE);

        }
        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
            boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
            // Category table create query
            String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("+ KEY_99 + " INTEGER,"
                    + KEY_ID1 + " TEXT," + KEY_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT)";
            String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS1 + "("
                    + KEY_ID1+ " TEXT," + KEY_NAME1+ " TEXT)";
            String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS2 + "("
                    + KEY_11+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_1+ " TEXT," + KEY_2+ " TEXT," + KEY_3+ " INTEGER," + KEY_4+ " INTEGER,"+ KEY_5+ " INTEGER," + KEY_6+ " INTEGER," + KEY_7+ " INTEGER," + KEY_8+ " INTEGER," + KEY_9+ " INTEGER," + KEY_10+ " TEXT)";
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE1);
            db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE2);
        }
        private boolean checkDataBase() {
            SQLiteDatabase checkDB = null;
            try {
                String myPath = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
                checkDB = SQLiteDatabase.openDatabase(myPath, null, SQLiteDatabase.OPEN_READONLY);
            } catch (SQLiteException e) {
            }
            if (checkDB != null) {
                checkDB.close();
            }
            return checkDB != null ? true : false;
        }
        private void copyDataBase() throws IOException {
            InputStream myInput = myContext.getAssets().open(DATABASE_NAME);
            String outFileName = DB_PATH + DATABASE_NAME;
            OutputStream myOutput = new FileOutputStream(outFileName);
            byte[] buffer = new byte[10];
            int length;
            while ((length = myInput.read(buffer)) > 0) {
                myOutput.write(buffer, 0, length);
            }
            myOutput.flush();
            myOutput.close();
            myInput.close();

        }
        // Upgrading database
        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            // Drop older table if existed
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS1);
            db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS2);
            // Create tables again
            onCreate(db);
        }

        // Added for adding new data
        public void insertlabel(String text,String id1,String id, String label) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();
            cv.put(KEY_99,text);
            cv.put(KEY_ID1,id1);
            cv.put(KEY_ID,id);
            cv.put(KEY_NAME,label);
            db.insert(TABLE_LABELS,null,cv);
            db.close();
        }
        public void insertlabel12(String id1, String label1) {
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
            ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
            cv1.put(KEY_ID1,id1);
            cv1.put(KEY_NAME1,label1);
            db.insert(TABLE_LABELS1,null,cv1);
            db.close();
        }
        /**
         * Inserting new lable into lables table
         * */
            public void insertLabel(String message1, String message2,String message3,String message4,String message5,String message6,String message7,String message8,String message9,String message10){
                SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

                ContentValues values = new ContentValues();

                values.put(KEY_1, message1);
                values.put(KEY_2, message2);
                values.put(KEY_10,message10);
                values.put(KEY_4,message4);
                values.put(KEY_5,message5);
                values.put(KEY_6,message6);
                values.put(KEY_7,message7);
                values.put(KEY_3,message3);
                values.put(KEY_9,message9);
                values.put(KEY_8,message8);


                // Inserting Row
                db.insert(TABLE_LABELS2, null, values);
                db.close(); // Closing database connection
            }

        public void insertLabel1(String label){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME1, label);

            // Inserting Row
            db.insert(TABLE_LABELS1, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }
        public void insertLabel2(String label){
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();


            ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
            values.put(KEY_NAME1, label);
            values.put(KEY_10, label);
            values.put(KEY_ID, label);

            db.insert(TABLE_LABELS2, null, values);
            db.close(); // Closing database connection
        }

        public List<String> getAllLabels(){
            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS1;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // closing connection
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            // returning lables
            return labels;
        }
        public List<String> andrew(){
            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  * FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);

            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    labels.add(cursor.getString(1));
                } while (cursor.moveToNext());
            }

            // closing connection
            cursor.close();
            db.close();

            // returning lables
            return labels;
        }
        public Cursor getAllEntries(){
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  count (*) FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cur = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            return  cur;

        }
        public Cursor getAllEntries1(){
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  count (*) FROM " + TABLE_LABELS2;
            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();

            Cursor cur1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            return  cur1;

        }

        public List<String> getAllLabels1(){
            List<String> labels = new ArrayList<String>();

            // Select All Query
            String selectQuery = "SELECT  count (*) FROM " + TABLE_LABELS;

            SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
            Cursor cursor1 = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, null);
            final ArrayList<String> row1 = new ArrayList<String>();
            // looping through all rows and adding to list
            if (cursor1.moveToFirst()) {
                do {
                    labels.add(cursor1.getString(1));
                } while (cursor1.moveToNext());
            }

            // closing connection
            cursor1.close();
            db.close();

            // returning lables
            return labels;
        }




        // Added to get Cursor for Simple CursorAdapter
        public Cursor getAllLabelsAsCursor() {
            String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"}; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
            return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_LABELS,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
        }

        public Cursor getAllLabelsExceptedSelected(long selected) {
            String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"};
            String whereclause = "rowid <> ?";
            String[] whereargs = new String[]{String.valueOf(selected)};
            return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_LABELS,
                    columns,
                    whereclause,
                    whereargs,
                    null,
                    null,
                    null
            );
        }

        public Cursor getByRowid(long id) {
            String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"};
            return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_LABELS, columns, "rowid=?", new String[]{String.valueOf(id)},
                    null, null, null

            );
        }
    }
```

Comment: Hello friends can anyone advise on the sqlite query for all details in tabel return based in spinner to based on first spinner value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is an example based upon some of the code from the question, that has 3 spinners the 2nd listing values as determined according to what is selected by spinner1. Likewise the 3rd listing values as determined by what is selected by spinner2.

In short each spinner has a **manageSprinner?** method (? being 1, 2 and 3 respectively).

The **manageSpinner?** methods retrieve the respective data.

- For 2 and 3 the respective data is determined according to the value passed, this value being the selected item from the spinner above it in the hierarchy (i.e. for spinner2 the selected item in spinner1, for spinner3 the selected item in spinner2).

They, the **managedSpinner?** methods instantiate the adapter if not already instantiated and for Spinners 1 and 2 add the onIstemSelected listener that invokes the **managerSpinner?** method of the spinner below it in the hierarchy.

If the respective adapter is already instantiated then it swaps the cursor to refresh the data displayed by the spinner.

- **Note** as **manageSpinner1** invokes **managerSpinner2** and as **manageSpinner2** invokes **manageSpinner3**. There is only the need to invoke **manageSpinner1**. That is there is always an item that is selected so the onItemSelected method is called from the outset.

The layout for the Activity **activity_main.xml** :-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Hello World!" />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner2"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
    <Spinner
        android:id="@+id/spinner3"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        />
</LinearLayout>
```

The Database helper **Databasehandler.java**

```
public class DatabaseHandler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    // Database Version
    public static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;

    public static final String DATABASE_NAME = "spinnerExample";
    private final Context myContext;
    private SQLiteDatabase myDataBase;
    // Database Name
    // Labels table name
    public static final String TABLE_LABELS = "labels"; //<<<< Made public
    public static final String TABLE_LABELS1= "labels1";
    public static final String TABLE_LABELS2= "labels2";
    // Labels Table Columns names
    public static final String KEY_ID4 = "input_label";
    public static final String KEY_ID12 = "id2";           //<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_ID = "id";
    public static final String KEY_99 = "sno";           //<<<< Made public//<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "name";       //<<<< made public
    public static final String KEY_ID1 = "id1";           //<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_NAME1 = "name1";
    public static final String KEY_1 = "number";           //<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_2 = "outletname";       //<<<< made public
    public static final String KEY_3 = "sunday";           //<<<< Made public
    public static final String KEY_4 = "monday";
    public static final String KEY_5 = "tuesday";
    public static final String KEY_6 = "wednesday";
    public static final String KEY_7 = "thursday";
    public static final String KEY_8 = "saturday";
    public static final String KEY_9 = "closed";
    public static final String KEY_10 = "calling";
    public static final String KEY_11 = "id3";
    public DatabaseHandler(Context context) {

        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        myDataBase = this.getWritableDatabase();
        this.myContext = context;
    }

    // Creating Tables
    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) {
        //boolean dbExist = checkDataBase();
        // Category table create query
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS + "("+ KEY_99 + " INTEGER,"
                + KEY_ID1 + " TEXT," + KEY_ID + " TEXT," + KEY_NAME + " TEXT)";
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE1 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS1 + "("
                + KEY_ID1+ " TEXT," + KEY_NAME1+ " TEXT)";
        String CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE2 = "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_LABELS2 + "("
                + KEY_11+ " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT," + KEY_1+ " TEXT," + KEY_2+ " TEXT," + KEY_3+ " INTEGER," + KEY_4+ " INTEGER,"+ KEY_5+ " INTEGER," + KEY_6+ " INTEGER," + KEY_7+ " INTEGER," + KEY_8+ " INTEGER," + KEY_9+ " INTEGER," + KEY_10+ " TEXT)";
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE1);
        db.execSQL(CREATE_CATEGORIES_TABLE2);
    }
    // Upgrading database
    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
        // Drop older table if existed
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS1);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_LABELS2);
        // Create tables again
        onCreate(db);
    }

    /**
     * Inserting new lable into lables table
     * */
    public void insertLabel(String message1, String message2,String message3,String message4,String message5,String message6,String message7,String message8,String message9,String message10){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();

        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_1, message1);
        values.put(KEY_2, message2);
        values.put(KEY_10,message10);
        values.put(KEY_4,message4);
        values.put(KEY_5,message5);
        values.put(KEY_6,message6);
        values.put(KEY_7,message7);
        values.put(KEY_3,message3);
        values.put(KEY_9,message9);
        values.put(KEY_8,message8);
        // Inserting Row
        db.insert(TABLE_LABELS2, null, values);
        //db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public void insertLabel1(String label){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME1, label);
        db.insert(TABLE_LABELS1, null, values);
        //db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }

    public void insertLabel2(String label){
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getWritableDatabase();
        ContentValues values = new ContentValues();
        values.put(KEY_NAME, label);
        db.insert(TABLE_LABELS, null, values);
        db.close(); // Closing database connection
    }


    public Cursor getAllLabelsForSpinner1AsCursor() {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"}; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(TABLE_LABELS2,columns,null,null,null,null,null);
    }


    public Cursor getAllLabelsForSpinner2AsCursor(String keyFromSinner1) {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"}; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TABLE_LABELS1,columns,
                DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME1 + " LIKE ?",
                new String[]{keyFromSinner1+"%"},
                null,null,null
        );
    }

    public Cursor getAllLabelsForSpinner3AsCursor(String keyFromSpinner2) {
        String[] columns = new String[]{"rowid AS _id, *"}; // Need _id column for SimpleCursorAdapter
        return this.getWritableDatabase().query(
                TABLE_LABELS,columns,
                DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME + " LIKE ?",
                new String[]{keyFromSpinner2 + "%"},
                null,null,null);
    }
}
```

- This has had the code not required for the example removed

The Activity **MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    DatabaseHandler mDH;
    Spinner mSpinner1,mSpinner2,mSpinner3;
    Cursor mSpinner1Csr,mSpinner2Csr,mSpinner3Csr;
    SimpleCursorAdapter mSpinner1Adapter,mSpinner2Adapter,mSpinner3Adapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        mSpinner1 = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
        mSpinner2 = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner2);
        mSpinner3 = this.findViewById(R.id.spinner3);
        mDH = new DatabaseHandler(this);
        addSomeTestingData(); // ADD testing data if none
        manageSpinner1(); // Manages spinner1 not that spinner 1 invokes manage spinner2 and spinnr manages spinner3

    }

    private void addSomeTestingData() {
        if(DatabaseUtils.queryNumEntries(mDH.getWritableDatabase(),DatabaseHandler.TABLE_LABELS) > 0) return;

        // Data for LABELS2 table (spinner 1 (note 1st column listed in spinner))
        mDH.insertLabel("A1","A2","A3","A4","A5","A6","A7","A8","A9","A10");
        mDH.insertLabel("B1","B2","B3","B4","B5","B6","B7","B8","B9","B10");
        mDH.insertLabel("L1","L2","L3","L4","L5","L6","L7","L8","L9","L10");

        // Data for LABELS1 table (spinner 2)
        mDH.insertLabel1("A1EXTRA1");
        mDH.insertLabel1("A1EXTRA2");
        mDH.insertLabel1("B1EXTRA1");
        mDH.insertLabel1("B1EXTRA2");
        mDH.insertLabel1("L1EXTRA1");
        mDH.insertLabel1("L1EXTRA2");

        // Data for LABELS table (spinner 3)
        mDH.insertLabel2("A1EXTRA1MORE1");
        mDH.insertLabel2("A1EXTRA1MORE2");
        mDH.insertLabel2("A1EXTRA2MORE1");
        mDH.insertLabel2("A1EXTRA2MORE2");
        mDH.insertLabel2("B1EXTRA1MORE1");
        mDH.insertLabel2("B1EXTRA1MORE2");
        mDH.insertLabel2("B1EXTRA2MORE1");
        mDH.insertLabel2("B1EXTRA2MORE2");
        mDH.insertLabel2("L1EXTRA1MORE1");
        mDH.insertLabel2("L1EXTRA1MORE2");
        mDH.insertLabel2("L1EXTRA2MORE1");
        mDH.insertLabel2("L1EXTRA2MORE2");

    }

    private void manageSpinner1() {
        mSpinner1Csr = mDH.getAllLabelsForSpinner1AsCursor();
        if (mSpinner1Adapter == null) {
            mSpinner1Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mSpinner1Csr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_1},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mSpinner1.setAdapter(mSpinner1Adapter);
            mSpinner1.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    manageSpinner2(mSpinner1Csr.getString(mSpinner1Csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_1)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
                }
            });
        } else {
            mSpinner1Adapter.swapCursor(mSpinner1Csr);
        }
    }
    private void manageSpinner2(String keyFromSpinner1) {
        mSpinner2Csr = mDH.getAllLabelsForSpinner2AsCursor(keyFromSpinner1);
        if (mSpinner2Adapter == null) {
            mSpinner2Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mSpinner2Csr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME1},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mSpinner2.setAdapter(mSpinner2Adapter);
            mSpinner2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
                @Override
                public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
                    manageSpinner3(mSpinner2Csr.getString(mSpinner2Csr.getColumnIndex(DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME1)));
                }

                @Override
                public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

                }
            });
        } else {
            mSpinner2Adapter.swapCursor(mSpinner2Csr);
        }
    }

    private void manageSpinner3(String keyForSpinner3) {
        mSpinner3Csr = mDH.getAllLabelsForSpinner3AsCursor(keyForSpinner3);
        if (mSpinner3Adapter == null) {
            mSpinner3Adapter = new SimpleCursorAdapter(
                    this,
                    android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,
                    mSpinner3Csr,
                    new String[]{DatabaseHandler.KEY_NAME},
                    new int[]{android.R.id.text1},
                    0
            );
            mSpinner3.setAdapter(mSpinner3Adapter);
        } else {
            mSpinner3Adapter.swapCursor(mSpinner3Csr);
        }
    }
}
```

## Note

**The above is intended solely as a demonstration of the technique and as such the technique will need to be incorporated and thus that code be adapted as part of that incorporation**

Comment: thank you. i am trying to retrieve the same output from same table.

Comment: @Leace, then you just use the same table in the queries.

Comment: how to give  color if that spinner value is already available in saving table. assuming the spinner2 data is retrieving from TABEL_LABELS  table. and while saving all data inserting in to table name TABEL_SAVE table.

Comment: what could be the way Edittext instead of Spinner1 ? . Based on Edittext input spinner2 and spinner3 change . Please share your expertise ?